# Subtracting mean from time series in AR(1) process

Tags: time-series

In Cryer and Chan the book *Timer Series with Application in R*. We find the following piece.

Consider the first-order autoregressive process, abbreviated  AR(1), in detail.

Assume the series is stationary and satisfies.

$Y_{t} = \phi Y_{t - 1} + e_{t}$

Where $e_{t}$ is a white noise process.

We assume that the process mean has been subtracted out so that
the series mean is zero.

I don't understand what this means.

Does this implicitly imply the following logic?

$Y_{t} = \phi Y_{t - 1} + e_{t} - \mu + \mu$

Suppose that:

$W_{t} =  \phi W_{t - 1} + e_{t} + \mu$

and that:

$X_{t} = W_{t} - \mu = \phi W_{t - 1} + e_{t} - \mu + \mu$

In this case, the time series $Y_{t}$ is stochastically equal to the following time series $X_{t}$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct but the meaning is simpler. The authors assume that $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_t\right] = 0$. If this were not the case, say $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_t\right] = \mu$, then substitute $Z_t = Y_t - \mu$ for $Y_t$ and follow along with the book.

Comment: Their calculations are *not* correct; $\mu$ is not the mean in their notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stationary AR(1) process given by:

$$W_t = \mu + \phi W_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$$

Then the mean is:

$$\mathbb{E}(W_t) = \frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$$

Note that the mean is not $\mu$ in general. If you subtract the mean and define a new process:

$$X_t := W_t - \mathbb{E}(W_t) = W_t - \frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$$

Therefore $W_t = X_t + \frac{\mu}{1-\phi}$ and you can substitute this back into the first equation to get:

$$
X_t + \frac{\mu}{1-\phi} = \mu + \phi \left(X_{t-1} + \frac{\mu}{1-\phi}\right) + \varepsilon_t
$$

Or:

$$
X_t = \mu \left[1 - \frac{1}{1-\phi} + \frac{\phi}{1-\phi}\right] + \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$

Which is just:

$$X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$$

This is a stationary AR(1) process with mean zero.

The issue with your derivation is that you use the wrong mean and then end up with an equation that doesn't have the same process on both sides ($X_t$ on the left and $W_{t-1}$ on the right).

Comment: +1 For pointing out the mistake I didn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "You can substitute this back into the first equation to get" $X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$.? Can you explain how this substitution works?@Chris Haug

Comment: @DanielDeWet I edited my answer to include intermediate steps, hope that helps.

Comment: What happened to the term $ \mu \left[1 - \frac{1}{1-\phi} + \frac{\phi}{1-\phi}\right]$ on the last line @ChrisHaug?

Comment: It certainly didn't cancel out.

Comment: The expression in brackets is equal to zero, yes.